# Permanently Block a Windows Service

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-services, foxit-reader, ninite

Foxit Reader comes with a windows service. It’s a cloud based service that I don't use and disable when I install the application.

When the application updates, via ninite, this service switches back to automatic.

Is there any way to put a block in place, such as a placeholder or changing permissions so the service cannot be edited?

I suppose I could settle for a scheduled task that runs at boot-up, to stop and disable the service, but that feels a little messy.

Comment: Why not mention what the app & service are? Someone might know a specific fix.

Comment: If you're talking about the Foxit Cloud service you should be able to uninstall it from the Control Panel's Programs and Features applet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with the scheduled task at boot. Here is the code to stop and disable the service.

```
sc config "FoxitReaderService" start= disabled
sc stop "FoxitReaderService"
```

**Edit:**

This worked, but when opening Foxit Reader, it would show a UAC to start the service.

So I have now empted the file, and changed permissions on it to read/execute only. Lets see how this goes.